# Getting the value of the first and second div into separate array

Tags: jquery, html

How can i get all the values of 1st and 2nd div into separate array?

I find the div with a value of `yes`.

Want to store all the names and numbers that has a yes div into two separate arrays.
here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('#nmme').eq(0).text() == 'yes') {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px">name</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px">number</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 50px">status</div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px">Michael </div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px">17</div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px" id="nmme">yes</div>

</div>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px">Vic </div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px">20</div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px" id="nmme">no</div>

</div>

<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px">Jose </div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px">50</div>

  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px" id="nmme">yes</div>

</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="button">
```

here's a fiddle:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/doobidoo/xpvt214o/138324/)

Comment: Are you asking like yes to one array and no into another array?

Comment: I want the name and numbers with yes  into two separate arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the modified code, hope it helps;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var names = [], numbers = [];
    $('div').each(function() {
     var current = $(this);
      if(current.find('div:last-child').text() == 'yes') {
        names.push(current.find('div.name').text());
        numbers.push(current.find('div.number').text());
      } 
    });
    console.log(names, numbers);
    $('#result').html('Array 1: ' + names.join(', ') + '<br>' + 'Array 2: ' + numbers.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px">name</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px">number</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 50px">status</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;  width: 65px" class="name">Michael </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px" class="number">17</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px">yes</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px" class="name">Vic </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px" class="number">20</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px">no</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px" class="name">Jose </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 65px" class="number">50</div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px">yes</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="button">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating yesArray and noArray as 2 different variables, then assigning the values when it's yes and no based on the condition.

Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/138455/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var yesArray = [];
    var noArray = [];
    $('div').each(function() {
        var elements = $(this).find('div');
      if ($(this).find('#nmme').eq(0).text() == 'yes') {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
        $(this).css('color', 'white');   
        yesArray.push({ 
            name : $(elements[0])[0].innerHTML,
          number : $(elements[1])[0].innerHTML
        });
      } else if ($(this).find('#nmme').eq(0).text() == 'no') {
          noArray.push({ 
            name : $(elements[0])[0].innerHTML,
          number : $(elements[1])[0].innerHTML
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(yesArray);
    console.log(noArray);
  });
});
```